# How to trigger a new JS function in console after I redirect to new url?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make a simple script that helps me reserve a online ticket when it comes available. I run the script in the Chrome console.

So this is the idea: If there is a ticket available, the script redirects me to a new URL. On the new URL I want to click a new button so it sends me to another URL again. So the script should redirect me two times in total.

This is the problem: The first redirect works fine, but the moment I get redirect to the new URL the console is cleared. So I can't target the new button and click it. Is there any way to fix this? Preserve the console and the running script when a new URL is opened? Or maybe send a function to the console when redirected to a new URL?

This is the first part of the code:

```
var checkNewTickets = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', document.location.href, true);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            var hasTickets = document.getElementsByClassName('counter-value')[0].textContent;
            if (hasTickets > 0) {
                console.log(hasTickets + ' kaartjes!');
                var href = document.querySelectorAll('.listings-item--title > h3 a')[0].getAttribute('href');
                var link = 'https://www.someurl.nl' + href;
                window.open(link, '_blank');
                alert('KAARTJES!');
                clearInterval(ticketSwapInterval);
            } else {
                console.log(hasTickets + ' - Nog geen kaartjes.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
var ticketSwapSeconds = 30;
var ticketSwapInterval = window.setInterval(checkNewTickets, ticketSwapSeconds * 1000);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: In order to preserve console go to Dev Tools -> Console -> Gear -> check Preserve Log. But I don't know if this will get you towards solving your problem.

Comment: Hi @Lixus Thanks for your response. I already tried that and it didn't work :(

Comment: Scripts are page-specific so when page is reloaded from a new URL no old scripts exist. You'll have to write a userscript or an extension.